# removing trailing and leading spaces from a file

Tags: c, string, malloc, whitespace

I am trying to read lines from a text file of unknown length. 
In the line there can be leading and trailing white-spaces until the string occurs.
So my first step is to read line by line and allocate memory for the strings. Then remove all the leading and trailing white spaces.
After that I want to check if the string has any white space characters in it which is an invalid character. For example the string can not look like this `"bad string"` but can look like this `"goodstring"`.
However when I call the function to remove the leading and trailing white spaces it also removes characters before or after a white space.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define NCHAR 64

char *readline (FILE *fp, char **buffer);
char *strstrip(char *s);


int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (readline (fp, &line)) {  /* read each line in 'fp' */
        printf (" line[%2zu] : %s\n", idx++, line);
        free (line);
        line = NULL;
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    return  0;
}

/* read line from 'fp' allocate *buffer NCHAR in size
 * realloc as necessary. Returns a pointer to *buffer
 * on success, NULL otherwise.
 */
char *readline (FILE *fp, char **buffer) 
{
    int ch;
    size_t buflen = 0, nchar = NCHAR;
    size_t n;
    char *invalid_character = " ";

    *buffer = malloc (nchar);    /* allocate buffer nchar in length */
    if (!*buffer) {
        fprintf (stderr, "readline() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) 
    {
        (*buffer)[buflen++] = ch;

        if (buflen + 1 >= nchar) {  /* realloc */
            char *tmp = realloc (*buffer, nchar * 2);
            if (!tmp) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc failed, "
                                "returning partial buffer.\n");
                (*buffer)[buflen] = 0;
                return *buffer;
            }
            *buffer = tmp;
            nchar *= 2;
        }
        strstrip(*buffer); //remove traiing/leading spaces
    }
    (*buffer)[buflen] = 0;           /* nul-terminate */


   if (invalid_character[n = strspn(invalid_character, *buffer)] == '\0') //check if a string has invalid character ' ' in it
    {
        puts(" invalid characters");

    } 

    if (buflen == 0 && ch == EOF) {  /* return NULL if nothing read */
        free (*buffer);
        *buffer = NULL;
    }

    return *buffer;
}
char *strstrip(char *s)
{
    size_t size;
    char *end;

    size = strlen(s);

    if (!size)
        return s;

    end = s + size - 1;
    while (end >= s && isspace(*end))
        end--;
    *(end + 1) = '\0';

    while (*s && isspace(*s))
        s++;

    return s;
}
```

Comment: What is or should be hapenning here: `invalid_character[n = strspn(invalid_character, buffer[i])] == '\0'` and what does the `i` do there? You want to find a space in the string and output `" valid characters"` if it is found? Please show what should happen when "the string that can not look like this" is inputted.

Comment: I don't understand why you are calling strstrip in your loop each time you read a character, since the function assumes the string is null terminated, but you haven't done that yet when it is called. You also don't use the return value of strstrip which would be used to indicate the start of the new string (you can't simply replace *buffer with it, though, since then your `free` won't work).

Comment: @KamilCuk if the string is inputed like this "bad string" then it will print out invalid characters otherwise nothing

Comment: @EdmCoff I don't understand what you mean when you said I wont be able to free the allocated memory

Comment: passing `char` to `isspace` risks undefined behavior, because the argument is of type `int`, and must be in the range 0 to `UCHAR_MAX`, or else `EOF`. The accepted answer doesn't fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to worry about the length of the string passed to `strstrip()`, simply iterate over all characters in the string removing whitespace characters, e.g. the following version removals *ALL* whitespace from `s`:

```
/** remove ALL leading, interleaved and trailing whitespace, in place.
 *  the original start address is preserved but due to reindexing,
 *  the contents of the original are not preserved. returns pointer
 *  to 's'. (ctype.h required)
 */
char *strstrip (char *s)
{
    if (!s) return NULL;                     /* valdiate string not NULL */
    if (!*s) return s;                       /* handle empty string */

    char *p = s, *wp = s;                    /* pointer and write-pointer */

    while (*p) {                             /* loop over each character */
        while (isspace ((unsigned char)*p))  /* if whitespace advance ptr */
            p++;
        *wp++ = *p;                          /* use non-ws char */
        if (*p)
            p++;
    }
    *wp = 0;    /* nul-terminate */

    return s;
}
```

(**note:** if the argument to `isspace()` is type `char`, a cast to `unsigned char` is required, see **NOTES** Section, e.g. [man 3 isalpha](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iscntrl_l.3.html))

**Removing only Excess Whitespace**

The following version removes leading and trailing whitespace and collapses multiple sequences of whitespace to a single space:

```
/** remove excess leading, interleaved and trailing whitespace, in place.
 *  the original start address is preserved but due to reindexing,
 *  the contents of the original are not preserved. returns pointer
 *  to 's'. (ctype.h required) NOTE: LATEST
 */
char *strstrip (char *s)
{
    if (!s) return NULL;                        /* valdiate string not NULL */
    if (!*s) return s;                               /* handle empty string */

    char *p = s, *wp = s;                      /* pointer and write-pointer */

    while (*p) {
        if (isspace((unsigned char)*p)) {                    /* test for ws */
            if (wp > s)                         /* ignore leading ws, while */
                *wp++ = *p;                   /* preserving 1 between words */
            while (*p && isspace (unsigned char)(*p))    /* skip remainder  */
                p++;
            if (!*p)                               /* bail on end-of-string */
                break;
        }
        if (*p == '.')                 /* handle space between word and '.' */
            while (wp > s && isspace ((unsigned char)*(wp - 1)))
                wp--;
        *wp++ = *p;                                      /* use non-ws char */
        p++;
    }
    while (wp > s && isspace ((unsigned char)*(wp - 1))) /* trim trailing ws */
        wp--;
    *wp = 0;    /* nul-terminate */

    return s;
}
```

(**note:** `s` must be *mutable* and therefore cannot be a *string-literal*)

Comment: thank you . It's your first unedited answer did exactly what I wanted it to do. Your edited answer dosen't print out "invalid characters" if there is a space in the string

Comment: The first answer removed all *excess* whitespace removing leading, compressing multiple interleaved, and removing trailing whitespace. This version removes *All* whitespace. I'll repost the orginal.

Comment: You know -- it's been a while since I looked at that. If `wp` is pointing to the last non-whitespace before being advanced, then there isn't a need, but I recall it being written for a corner-case (one you probably pointed out `:)` I'll make another pass through.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It can be removed from the 1st completely (no special cases there). In the second the `/* handle space between word and '.' */` is required for the circumstance of `" hello  world  ."` to not leave a whitespace before the sentence ending `'.'` The `/* trim trailing ws */` in the second was due to the factoring of the loop and `*wp++ = *p;` potentially including a trailing `space` if the previous characters was `'.'` followed by `" \0"`. The `if {..} if {..}` could probably be refactored into a `if {..} else if {..} ... else {..}` and eliminate them both.

Comment: `if (!*s) return s;` not needed in first `()` although not objectionable either.

Comment: `if (*p == '.')` unclear in the 2nd `()`.  Why test for a `.`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That is a good point. It was originally for a sentence case. (specifically ending in a `'.'` in the original case) Ideally, you would add tests for any other line-ending you wanted to ensure were not left dangling with whitespace before them. `ispunct()` is too broad, so you would probably want independent tests for `'.'`, `','`, `'!'`, and `'?'`.

Comment: `isspace` cannot be safely used on elements of `char *` strings, unless we control their contents  and know that all the character values are positive.

Comment: @Kaz - You are 100% correct. In all places where `isspace(c)` is used above, it should technically be `isspace ((unsigned char)(c))` if `c` is type `char` instead of `unsigned char`. Thank you for pointing that out. (you see it so many times omitted)

Comment: No, I didn't get a red mailbox thingy... I'll take a look at your link right now.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, sure sir, even for your comment I didn't get notification, thank you for your views on it, btw I posted an answer too in same thread, thanks again for posting your views on same, cheers.