# I have a string and I want to remove any - ,( ,) ,& ,$ ,# ,! ,[ ,] ,{ ,} ," ,' from the beginning or end of the word

Tags: c, string, punctuation

Each word is a string, there is no white space between them since each word is read using scanf.

If it is between the words just ignore those.

For example:

```
"..!Hello!!!."
```

would produce

```
Hello
```

and

```
"??Str'ing!!"
```

would produce

```
   Str'ing
```

Since I'm a beginner, I'm only allowed to use loops and the standard `<string.h>` header in C.

I already made a helper function that keeps reading each index and returns true if the character matches any of the ones listed above so far.

I have this so far but it removes punctuation from the entire code and not just the beginning and end of words:

```
void punc(char *str) {
    char *pr = str;
    char *pw = str;
    while (*pr) {
        *pw = *pr++;
         pw += (is_punc(*pw) == false);
    }
    *pw = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: When you are reading your index, just check if the *last* or *next* character after the one you want to remove is *whitespace* -- if so -- remove the character at the *current* index (you can use `memmove` to adjust the whole string, or a pair of pointers (read pointer and write pointer) and just skip writing the characters to be removed). You can use `strspn()` to jump to the next character in your remove list or `strcspn()` to jump over chars not it the list.

Comment: Here is an example for [removing trailing and leading spaces from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257845/3422102) that you can adapt to removing any character.

Comment: What should happen to the string "`abc'-'def`"?  Should the punctuation be removed or left unchanged or what?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler since it is between the string it would be left unchanged

Comment: So you're looking to delete only sequences of selected punctuation when the character before the sequence is a 'space' (or beginning of string), or the character after the sequence is a 'space' (or end of string)?  So the punctuation in "`abc '-' def`" should go because there is both a space before and a space after the punctuation sequence (and both spaces should be left in the string)?  Also, you omitted `?` in the title but showed the character being removed — so the title of the question is wrong?

Comment: yes you are correct, each string is like a word and since '-' is all punctuation it should be removed. However, if  "abc '-' def" is one big string then no, '-' should not be removed since it is in the middle of the string.

Comment: The `.` is not part of the removal list in your question's title, so that and the `"..!Hello!!!."` example don't fit together; you should rectify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do it is to shave off all punctuation characters from the front and the back of the char array, for this sample I'm using your pointers, moving them along the char array till the first non-punctuation character is found, null terminate it and return the pointer to the 1st non-punctuation character:

[**Live sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qCofPDWN3vaRZd38)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *punc(char *str)
{
    int iterations = 0;
    char *pr = str;                   
    char *pw = &str[strlen(str) - 1]; //pointer to str end
    while (ispunct(*pr))  // I'm using ctype.h ispunct() standard function here 
    {                     // You can repalce it by your helper function    
        pr++;
        printf("it%d ", iterations++); //count and print iterations
    }
    while (ispunct(*pw))
    {      
        if(pw <= pr){  //using pointer comparison to avoid unnecessary iterations
           break;
        }
        pw--;
        printf("it%d ", iterations++);  //count and print iterations
    }   
    *(pw + 1) = '\0';
    return pr;
}

int main()
{
    char str1[] = ".[],!hello-.,?!-worl.d.?(!.";  //test1
    char str2[] = "!.';?";                        //test2   
    char *result1, *result2; 

    result1 = punc(str1);
    printf("  %s\n", result1);    
    result2 = punc(str2);
    printf("  %s\n", result2);    
    strcpy(str1, result1);  //if you want to really replace str with new string   
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
it0 it1 it2 it3 it4 it5 it6 it7 it8 it9   hello-.,?!-worl.d
it0 it1 it2 it3 it4
```

Comment: The examples in the question morphed and simplified.  Originally, one of the inputs was `"Hello I am a str'ing, and I am called Jack-Tack!. My -mom is Darlean."` (where the double quotes at either end are more C string notation than part of the data).

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense now

Comment: @new_hello_world, glad to help.

Comment: Hello @anastaciu, I was wondering how I could fix the issue of it not going into memory underflow if a string only contains puncutiaon, such as something like this "!.';?". In this I would just want to get rid of everything but it goes into memory underflow.

Comment: @new_hello_world You can compare pointers to check when they pass by each other, if this happens it means that none of them found nothing other than punctuation and you can then return the result. I edited in the changes in the answer.